# I am using a modal view to display content on the screen but keyboard covering some field

Tags: iphone

I am displaying a modal dialog but the keyboard is covering some of the editable fields.  Is there any way of making the view move automatically...or must I manually write the code required to do this? i.e. change the location of the modal view etc

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:editViewController];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [editViewController release];

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the [UIKeyboardWillShowNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html), [UIKeyboardWillHideNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) notifications using [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and use a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) to allow the user to scroll down. Set the UIScrollView contentSize property to your normal full frame, and resize the scroll view's frame as the keyboard appears and disappears.  The size and animation duration of the keyboard can be obtained using this code in the method handling UIKeyboardWillShow/HideNotifications:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

NSValue *keyboardBoundsValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
[keyboardBoundsValue getValue:&keyboardBounds];

NSValue* value = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
[value getValue:&duration];
```

Another tip for handling these cases - when you rotate the device, you will receive both notifications (hide+show) in very quick succession.